# How to edit rows from DataGridView? MS Access Database

Tags: database, vb.net, sql-update

Seems that this is the only query that I don't know, and don't understand. I've set a Query for my Edit Button and here's the code.

```
ExecuteQuery("Update ICT11 set [Author] = '" & AuthorTxt.Text & "', [Publisher] = '" & PublisherTxt.Text & "', [Subject Code] = '" & SubcodeTxt.Text & "', [Price] = '" & PriceTxt.Text & "', [DiscountAmount] = '" & DiscountTxt.Text & "' Where [Book Name] = '" & BooknameTxt.Text & "'")
```

Also this is the Module for connecting to the Database

```
Module SQLDatabase
Public provider As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Anthony\Desktop\BookSelection\DataBase\BookListUE.accdb"
Public myConnection As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(provider)
Public sql As String
Public cmd As OleDbCommand
Public da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter
Public dt As New DataTable
Function ExecuteQuery(ByVal Query As String) As DataTable

    Dim sqlDT As New DataTable

    Dim sqlCon As New OleDbConnection(provider)
    Dim sqlDA As New OleDbDataAdapter(Query, sqlCon)
    Dim sqlCB As New OleDbCommandBuilder(sqlDA)

    sqlDA.Fill(sqlDT)
    Return sqlDT

End Function
```

End Module

The functions on the Edit button seem to work fine as I don't encountered any Exceptions. However it doesn't really update the database, together with DataGridView.

Comment: You need to spend a bit more time learning about databases, SQL and ADO.NET. If you have an `UPDATE` statement that is supposed to save specific values to a single existing record, how does it make sense to call `Fill` on a data adapter and populate a `DataTable` with the results? It doesn't. If you want to save specific values then you call `ExecuteNonQuery` on a command.

Answer (score 1):

You are going about this in completely the wrong way.  You use a data adapter to populate a `DataTable` and bind that to the grid.  Any changes the user makes locally should be made to that `DataTable`.

If they edit via the grid, that happens automatically.  If they edit via `TextBoxes` and the like then those changes can still be pushed to the `DataTable` automatically if you bind the `TextBoxes` as well.  Otherwise, you should manually update the `DataTable` with the data from the `TextBoxes`.  Here's an example of binding to both the grid and the `TextBoxes`:

```vb
BindingSource1.DataSource = myDataTable
DataGridView1.DataSource = BindingSource1
TextBox1.DataBindings.Add("Text", BindingSource1, "Column1")
TextBox2.DataBindings.Add("Text", BindingSource1, "Column2")
```

If you do that then selecting a row in the grid will automatically populate the `TextBoxes` with the data for that row.  Any edits made in the `TextBoxes` will be reflected in the grid when you navigate to another row.  If you weren't binding then you would copy data from the grid to the `TextBoxes`:

```vb
Dim row = DirectCast(BindingSource1.Current, DataRowView)

TextBox1.Text = CStr(row("Column1"))
TextBox2.Text = CStr(row("Column2"))
```

and then back again:

```vb
Dim row = DirectCast(BindingSource1.Current, DataRowView)

row("Column1") = TextBox1.Text
row("Column2") = TextBox2.Text
```

Note the use of the `BindingSource`, which is intended to be a one-stop-shop for accessing and manipulating bound data.  Note also that, when you bind a `DataTable`, the data actually comes from its `DefaultView` property, which is type `DataView`, rather than its `Rows` property, which is type `DataRowCollection`.  For that reason, each item is a `DataRowView` rather than a `DataRow`.  Also, note that you may not be able to use the `Current` item when copying the changes back, depending on when/where you do it.  If the selection has already changed by that point, you will have to remember the row that is being edited by assigning it to a field:

```vb
Private editingRow As DataRowView

'...

If editingRow IsNot Nothing Then
    editingRow("Column1") = TextBox1.Text
    editingRow("Column2") = TextBox2.Text
End If

editingRow = DirectCast(BindingSource1.Current, DataRowView)

TextBox1.Text = CStr(editingRow("Column1"))
TextBox2.Text = CStr(editingRow("Column2"))
```

You can make as many changes as you like to the `DataTable` before saving, i.e. you can but you don't have to save after each edit.  Once you're ready to save, you use a data adapter - preferably the same one but not necessarily - to save the changes from the `DataTable` to the database by calling `Update`.  There's no "refreshing" to be done on the grid because it already reflects the changes in the bound `DataTable` before they are saved.

Here are some examples I wrote some time ago that may help you:

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469872

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469518

In all the ADO.NET code in the first thread, note the use of parameters rather than string concatenation to get values into SQL code.  To learn why and how to do that, check this out:

http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html